# Обратиться к номеру ячейки в массиве по имени элемента

Tags: perl, список, хеширование

Простая задача - обратиться к номеру элемента в массиве по его значению. Не учитывая коллизии получилось так:

```
my $i = 0;
my %mapping = map {$_ => $i++} @heights; #@heights - массив чисел
```

Однако, этот вариант перезаписывает значение по ключу $_, если в массиве встретились два одинаковых числа. Как преобразовать этот код, чтобы сделать %mapping - хешем списков? Т.е., у каждого ключа будет список номеров ячеек массива heights, где этот ключ встретился.

Comment: Уточните задачу: найти индекс первого элемента с заданным значением, или индексы всех элементов с этим значением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use Data::Dumper;

my @heights = (38, 21, 32, 38, 21, 21, 9); 
my %mapping;

my $i = -1; 
map { $i++; push @{ $mapping{$_} //= [] },  $i; } @heights;

print Dumper \%mapping;
```

**Вывод**:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '21' => [
                1,
                4,
                5
              ],
      '38' => [
                0,
                3
              ],
      '32' => [
                2
              ],
      '9' => [
               6
             ]
    };
```

Comment: `//= []` => `||= []` :-)

Comment: @edem

Работает, спасибо =) Заодно, узнал, как пользоваться Data::Dumper

Только вопрос: а что конкретно делает эта строчка? `||= []`
И \ перед обращением к хешу

Comment: @АлександрЧи, `$a //= []` равнозначно `$a = $a // []`, что в свою очередь равнозначно `if (not defined $a) { $a = [] }`. В данном же случае таким образом просто инициируем пустым массивом значение хэша. А \ перед хэшем просто берёт ссылку на него.

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае задача решается с помощью [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use List::MoreUtils qw/firstidx indexes/;

my @data = ( 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2 );

# ищем первый индекс злемента со значением 1:
my $idx = firstidx { $_ == 1 } @data;
say $idx;

# ищем все индексы злементов со значением 1:
my @indexes = indexes { $_ == 1 } @data;
say join ',', @indexes;
```

Если хочется именно свой велосипед соорудить - имеет смысл смотреть как всё устроено внутри этого модуля. Там много чего ещё полезного есть :)

P.S. Ну и не стоит обходить вниманием и [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util), и [Array::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Utils).

---

Если же таких обращений может быть много, то да, имеет смысл сконвертировать массив в хэш списков индексов. Вот, набросал практически готовый вариант:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;

my @data = ( 9, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2 );
my %indexes = array2indexes( \@data );

say 'Indexes of 1: '.( $indexes{1} ? join( ',', @{ $indexes{1} } ) : 'none' );
say 'Indexes of 2: '.( $indexes{2} ? join( ',', @{ $indexes{2} } ) : 'none' );
say 'Indexes of 9: '.( $indexes{9} ? join( ',', @{ $indexes{9} } ) : 'none' );
say 'Indexes of 7: '.( $indexes{7} ? join( ',', @{ $indexes{7} } ) : 'none' );

# функция конвертирует массив в хэш, ключами которого являются
# элементы исходного масссива, а значениями - списки индексов
# этих самых элементов:
sub array2indexes
{
    my ($array) = @_;
    my $i = 0;
    my %indexes;
    for ( @{$array} ) {
        unless ( defined $indexes{$_} ) {
            $indexes{$_} = [ $i++ ];
        }
        else {
            push @{ $indexes{$_} }, $i++;
        }
    }
    return wantarray ? %indexes : \%indexes;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Indexes of 1: 1,5
Indexes of 2: 2,4,6
Indexes of 9: 0
Indexes of 7: none
```